# Finding the length of a curve?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, parametric

With the information given:

$$x=\frac{y^4}{8}+\frac{1}{4y^2}\,,\ \  1 \le y \le 2$$

I must find the exact length of the curve.

I use this formula to find it: $$\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2}\ dy $$

So of course,  I should find what 1 + (dx/dy)^2 is.

This is what I got:

$$\frac{y^6 -y^{-6}+2}{4} $$

So . . .

$$\int_1^2\sqrt{\frac{y^6-y^{-6}+2}{4}} \, dy$$

I don't know... It just looks really funky to me. Should I do a $u$ substitution? Like $u=y^6-y^{-6}+2$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was a little mistake made when squaring, you should have $$\frac{y^6+2+y^{-6}}{4}\tag{1}$$
inside the square root.
And the square root of (1) is very nice, in our interval it is $$\frac{y^3+y^{-3}}{2}.$$

**Remark:** Many arclength exercises, including this one, are rather contrived. The coefficients were carefully chosen to make the thing we are integrating "magically" simplify.

Comment: so should I use u substitution to evaluate this? u = y^3 + y^-3

Comment: To integrate, no substitution. You are just integrating powers. For $y^3$ you get $\frac{1}{4}y^4$. For $y^{-3}$ you get $\frac{1}{-2}y^{-2}$.

Comment: I'm hard-pressed to think of an arclength exercise that isn't either contrived (such as this one) or computationally trivial (such as a circle.) I suppose the case of the arc-length of an ellipse (and the connection to elliptic functions thereof) is a counter-example, but that's not really at an 'exercise' level.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{2}\left(y^{3}-y^{-3}\right),
$$
hence
$$
1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2}\left(y^{3}+y^{-3}\right)^2
$$
and thus
$$
\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2}\,dy=\int_{1}^{2}
\frac{(y^3+y^{-3})\,dy}{2}.
$$